# Subversion Commit Troubles

Tags: svn, repository, commit

I cannot do a simple commit (svn commit file.php) from within the working directory.  Or, by referencing the working directory and file (svn commit ~/webDev/ricalsin/trunk/config/site.php) Shouldn't that be possible using either approach?  Both approaches generate the same terminal window response - which is not what tutorials say.

I attached a screenshot of the terminal window after making the attempt (below).  This is an apache2 server running on a local computer.  I am able to checkout a directory without a problem.

So sorry for the noobiness.  Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn` has dropped you into a text editor, so you can edit the log message for that commit.
You can stop this from happening by supplying the message on the command line with the
`-m` argument, e.g.

```
svn commit file.php -m "your message here"
```

Or just edit the message and exit the editor -- svn should proceed with the commit.

Note that `svn ci` is recognized as an abbreviation for `svn commit`.

Comment: Oh, simple.  Thanks.  I read that somewhere, but forgot.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: ...bummer, I don't have enough "credits" to even vote you up, Jim.  (Maybe I should just quit and go back to Windows.)  (-;

Comment: @Ric: I just chipped in a +1 on your question to get you started.  Don't spend it all in one place!  :-)  By the way, you can mark my answer as "accepted", and we'll both get a reputation bonus...

Comment: okay!  (and to think I was considered an expert on Winblows)  BTW: Playing around, I noticed that simply checking out a directory does not seem to overwrite an existing file in the working directory - but if I delete the wd file, it replaces it on co.  Is that right, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Ric: Doing `svn checkout` when you're already in a working directory is kind of unusual...usually you'd do `svn update` instead.  I'm not sure what's supposed to happen in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Run `svn ci` for checking in from your working copy.